# Unwanted result by exploding a string and adding p tags

Tags: php, string, explode

here is a text made in notepad++

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit

lorem ipsum
dolor sit
```

I stored the text inside a mysql table
column type -  `text`
collation - `utf8mb4_croatian_ci`

getting the text I need to add some tags, like this:

```
$blocks = explode("\n\n", $str);  // $str is the text  
$res = '';
foreach($blocks as $block){
    $block = str_replace("\n", "<br>\n", $block);
    $block = "<p>" . $block . "</p>";
    $res .= $block . "\n\n";
}
echo $res;
```

I'm expecting following:

```
<p>lorem ipsum<br>
dolor sit</p>

<p>lorem ipsum<br>
dolor sit</p>
```

Instead of the above I'm getting the following:

```
<p>lorem ipsum<br>
dolor sit<br>
<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
dolor sit</p>
```

So I need firstly to explode the given string by `double new lines`
and then - inside the each block - replace single new lines by `<br>`
and finally cover each block with `<p></p>`

Btw earlier I worked on this table and with the same php code - and it worked
Today, suddenly - I'm getting the unwanted result

I tried to change end of lines from `crlf` to `lf` and vice versa - without success

**update**

what I see now:

if the string is defined by php - it works

if the string is made by a textarea or contenteditable div - it works

if the string is copy-paste from notepad++ to a cell table - it gives the above - unwanted result

so I think - something is problem with end of lines

Comment: Doesn't appear to be reproducible - demo: https://3v4l.org/oEuRF . Double-check the exact content of the string in your environment. Depends exactly where your line ending characters are and how many there are.

Comment: `something is problem`...yes probably - that's what I already said. In notepad++ you can make it "show all symbols" so you can see exactly what characters are present. Compare it to what's being submitted from the other sources you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, it's probably a **whitespace character issue**.
If your text isn't supposed to contain anything else than spacings and newlines, you probably should remove all others first (mostly `\r` and `\t`).

A simple regexp could do the trick :

```
$cleaned_string = preg_replace('/[\r\t]*/m', '', $string);
```